# Is there any way to get the oldest file using mule requester?

Tags: mule, mule-component

I have a requirement where i need to process oldest file first using mule requester.In Inbound property from mule requester we get time stamp.From there we can fetch time of file.But how to process it?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a custom component to do this because there's no way to do it out of the box (at least up to Mule 3.7.2).

Indeed the `FileMessageRequester` calls `FileMessageDispatcher.getNextFile` to retrieve the next file to process in the polled directory. This method relies on a private method for selecting the first file to process, method which doesn't do any ordering (nor offer any option to inject ordering), as you can see [here](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.7.2/transports/file/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/file/FileMessageDispatcher.java#L149-L160).

Comment: can i use interceptor class to modify the sequencing?

Comment: Yes, you could, it's hackish but using a tool like Byteman would allow you to alter the behaviour of `FileMessageDispatcher.getFirstFile` in order to return the first one based on time.

Comment: I have found somewhere to use OlderFirstComparator provided in endpoint.But it's not returning older file first?

Answer (score 0):

I find my answer.Here is code snippet to get ordered mule message by file timestamp.

```
DefaultMessageCollection test =(DefaultMessageCollection) message;
        List<MuleMessage> theList = new ArrayList<MuleMessage>();
        MuleMessage[] msg=test.getMessagesAsArray();
         for (MuleMessage muleMessage : msg) {
             theList.add(muleMessage);

        }

        Collections.sort(theList, new Comparator<MuleMessage>(){
            public int compare(MuleMessage obj1, MuleMessage obj2) {
                return ((Long)(obj1.getInboundProperty("timestamp"))).intValue()-((Long)(obj2.getInboundProperty("timestamp"))).intValue(); 
            }
        });
```